# How would you replicate try/catch/finally using On Error Goto

Tags: vb.net

Suppose in VB.NET you have:

```
Try
   Debug.Print("Trying...")
Catch ex as Exception
   throw new Exception("Exception", ex)
Finally
   Debug.Print("Finally...")
End Try
```

How would you write this using the "On Error Goto" construct? (please no questions asking why I would want to do this, just curious if it can be done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
   On Error Goto ErrHandler
    Debug.Print("Trying...")

    Goto Finish

    ErrHandler:
      Debug.Print("Exception...")
      On Error Goto ErrHandler2
      Debug.Print("Throwing another error, I guess...")

      Goto Finish2

      ErrHandler2:
      Debug.Print("Exception 2...")

      Finish2:
      Debug.Print("Finally 2...")


    Finish:
    Debug.Print("Finally...")
```

Comment: what if the catch was "Throw new Exception("Ha!", ex). Then this doesn't work. See updated question...

Comment: You would need another Error Handler in the Error Handler code.  That's a lot of Gotos.

Comment: there must be a way to do it cleanly...

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant. You are just going from one label to the next... The function that called this method will never receive the exception that was thrown in the catch clause.

Comment: Nope On Error Goto = mess waiting to get messier.

Comment: The only way the calling function would get the error is if you passed it back (probably via a ByRef field).  That's why On Error Goto is so bad (along with all the Gotos or course).

Comment: @Holger, it's interesting how we can't figure out how to mimic it, I would have thought that people who used "On Error Goto" have figured out some sort of a pattern for this.

Answer (score 0):

No comment...

```
Public Sub PleaseDontMakeMeDoThis()
    On Error Goto ExceptionHandler
    Debug.Print("Trying...")
    Debug.Print("Finally...")
    Exit Sub
ExceptionHandler:
    Debug.Print("Exception...")
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

The only difference is if, in the try/catch, an exception is thrown in the catch, then the finally will still be processed.  I'm not sure how you'd get it to also handle that.  I suppose you could do something like this:

```
Public Sub PleaseDontMakeMeDoThis()
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print("Trying...")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo PseudoFinally
        Debug.Print("Exception...")
    End If
PseudoFinally:
    Debug.Print("Finally...")
End Sub
```

But in this case it's just eating the exception in the "catch block" instead of letting the calling code handle it.  In short, I don't think there's anyway to entirely mimic a try/catch in every way.  If there was, Microsoft wouldn't have had a need to replace VB's error handling :)

Comment: not really right, finally gets executed even if an exception is thrown

Comment: Sorry, forgot the resume next.

Comment: won't really work, what if the catch was changed... see updated question...